# How can I configure zoom extent in Mapbox when generating raster tilesets from GeoTIFF?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

**GOAL**

I'm using Mapbox to generate raster tilesets from raw GeoTIFFs. The GeoTIFFs have a resolution such that a single pixel represents roughly a 5km x 5km square on the map. I hope to generate and host the raster tilesets using Mapbox and then display them in a Mapbox GL JS application.

**PROBLEM**

The issue I'm running into is extreme blurriness at high zoom levels. Below is a section of central Nigeria at about a zoom level of 7 displayed in our Mapbox GL JS app vs. the raw GeoTiff viewed in QGIS. The blurriness is of course worse at even higher zooms.

[image: Two screen captures contrasting blurry raster rendering in MapBox vs. crisp pixellation in QGIS]

I created this raster tileset by uploading a sample GeoTIFF into Mapbox Studio (I've also used the [Uploads API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/uploads/)). The Tileset viewer in Studio displays a footnote that reads:

> **Zoom Extent**
>
> z0 – z5. Data will be overzoomed to z22, but simplified past 5.

I can verify this by looking at the network requests in the dev tools as I zoom in on the map – it actually seems that no new tiles are requested above z4.

**QUESTION**

Does Mapbox have any way to manually configure the zoom extent (specifically, the max zoom) for which raster tilesets are generated?

**WHAT I'VE TRIED/RESEARCHED**

I’ve clicked through to the [Adjust Tileset Zoom Extent help page](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/adjust-tileset-zoom-extent/), which states:

> For raster tilesets, the uploaded image resolution sets the minzoom
> and maxzoom levels. Higher resolution images will result in the
> tileset rendering at more zoom levels.

Again, the data I'm working with is of fixed resolution so I'm hoping to find a way to have tilesets generated for higher zoom levels regardless of image resolution. [Mapbox Tiling Service](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/mapbox-tiling-service/#create-a-tileset-source) and [Tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) both have custom configuration rules for specifying the max zoom (past which, simplification occurs) when creating vector tilesets. However, neither seems to handle rasters. The Uploads API does handle raster tilesets, but doesn't seem to have any zoom extent configuration options.

I've also tried adjusting various frontend configuration options in the Mapbox GL JS client like the source `tileSize` and the `raster-resampling` paint property, but to little avail. I'm definitely open to other suggestions for how to get crisp pixels at higher zoom levels, but mostly hoping there's some simple method I'm missing for getting Mapbox to generate raster tiles past z4/z5. I think even z0-z7 would be sufficient.

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I'm struggling with the same...